# unreachable code at line 104: youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);

Tags: java, android, unreachable-code

Unreachable code    Home.java   /idg/src/com/idg/omv    line 104    Java Problem

I'm getting an error stating unreachable code at line 104 which is:

```
youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
```

I'm not sure exactly why this is happening or what I can do to resolve it (I've never encountered it before). From what I've read it seems like the issue is in regards to part of my code being out of scope - I simply don't see how I can resolve the issue. (I've tried adding a few }'s without success)

### SOURCE:

```
public class Home extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener,
        YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener {

    public static final String API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "o7VVHhK9zf0";
    public static final String VIDEO1_ID = "xVHHJqntuXI";
    public static final String VIDEO2_ID = "YWteQj_q3Ro";
    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView1;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView2;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView3;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView4;
    private String[] drawerListViewItems;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerListView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;



    private YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader;
    ScrollView mainScrollView;
    Button fav_up_btn;
    Button fav_dwn_btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

         // get list items from strings.xml
        drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);

        // get ListView defined in activity_main.xml
        drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

                // Set the adapter for the list view
        drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
                );
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 

        drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    }

     @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

             // call ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(), if it returns true
            // then it has handled the app icon touch event
            if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        mainScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.groupScrollView);

        youTubeThumbnailView1 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview1);
        youTubeThumbnailView1.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        fav_up_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn);

        fav_up_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean favIsUp = fav_up_btn.getBackground().getConstantState()
                                            .equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav_up_btn).getConstantState());  
                //set the background                            
                fav_up_btn.setBackgroundResource(favIsUp ? R.drawable.fav_dwn_btn : R.drawable.fav_up_btn);
            }
        });



        youTubeThumbnailView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView2 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview2);
        youTubeThumbnailView2.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView3 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview3);
        youTubeThumbnailView3.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView4 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview4);
        youTubeThumbnailView4.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }

        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

        youTubePlayer = player;

        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView,
            YouTubeInitializationResult error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView,
            YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader) {

        youTubeThumbnailLoader = thumbnailLoader;
        thumbnailLoader
                .setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailLoadedListener());

        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VIDEO_ID);

    }

    private final class ThumbnailLoadedListener implements
            YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0, ErrorReason arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0, String arg1) {

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: yes? there is a return before that line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

all statements which come after this code will become unreachable (except `catch/finally`). that is why you are seeing error.

Remove last return statement (or) put it in condition block (like first one).

Answer (score 1):

```
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

This line occurs before the error causing the function to return in *all cases*. You either need to put that statement in a condition (such as the if statement above) or remove it entirely.